# How do I change the Multisite URL?

Tags: multisite, site-url, network-admin

The links in the navbar menu, in (My sites > Manage the network) are pointing (and keep redirecting) to incorrect URLs.

The incorrect URLs are in this pattern:

```
https://https//www.domain.com/wp-admin/network/
https://https//www.domain.com/wp-admin/network/sites.php
https://https//www.domain.com/wp-admin/network/settings.php
```

Even if I manually entered the correct URL without the repeated https, I am redirected to the wrong URL again.

It seems that `https//www` is set somewhere instead of `https://www`, I can't find where.

Places that I have looked and they were OK:

- wp-config.php (DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE)
- .htaccess
- site table (domain only, with www but not https or /)
- options table (situeurl and home)
- sitemeta table

I haven't updated any of the above-mentioned. They were OK. (So not cache issue)

I tried the Search option of my phpMyAdmin using `https//www` but didn't return any match.

Where else should I look?

Answer (score 11):

There are 5 values need to change. 
From database.

```
wp_options: options named “siteurl” and “home”

wp_site

wp_sitemeta: the option named “siteurl”

wp_blogs: any entries in the “domains” column that have the old domain name

wp_#_options: Each sub-site will have sets of tables that correspond to the blog_id in the wp_blogs table. You need to go to the wp_#_options table, where # corresponds to the blog_id, and update the “siteurl” and “home” settings in that table.
```

Note: In most cases, you may/will need to update an entry in your WP-Config.php file. The code I would recommend taking a look at is the code snippet here:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysite.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Comment: ahhh the wp_blogs table. i knew i was missing something. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The multisite URLs are available for editing on the Network Admin, Sites page, then edit the subsites (click on a subsite's edit link, then the Settings tab). You can only do this for subsites.

The 'siteurl' and 'home' values should be the full URL of the site, including the protocol, as in https://www.example.com/site1 . If those values do not include the protocol (the 'https://' part), then any links of the site will include the 'double protocol' value that you are experiencing.

The main site URL cannot be edited on this screen; go into the wp-options table to fix that (in two places).

I never change the site URLs in the wp-config.php file, as suggested by other answers and comments. The proper place (IMHO) to make the site URL setting is the wp-options table (for the main site), and the procedure above for the sub-sites.

Note that the above procedure will also let you change any incorrect URLs saved by any plugins that write to the options table. I've had to change that a couple of times when I moved a site to a new domain.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have double checked the wp-options table and both fields have the full URL with the protocol HTTPS. I have also tried changing it to HTTP but the double protocol issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change at two places:

1- in Database wp_blogs table change `example.com to www.example.com`

2- in wp-config.php change `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com'); to define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com');`

It will work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked **wp_blogs**? Is it OK?

Also, make sure that all the pre-defined constants in your **wp-config.php** file are commented out. Otherwise, they will override the database settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just checked blogs table, they are all OK. The domain is ```www.domain.com```, no http or https. and the paths are OK too. The constants aren't commented out but they are OK

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your **wp-config.php** file,

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yoursite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yoursite.com');
```

If still, you face the issue then login to your **phpMyAdmin** and then,

- Choose the name of the database from the left-hand sidebar and open the **wp_options** database table.
- Search for the site URL and home rows, click edit to modify the URLs. You can see a box in front of **option_value** to fill in the URL.
- Click on the **Go** button to save settings.

Also, make your URL start with https:// not http// (you mentioned above)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The steps were previously done as mentioned above.

Comment: Can you try to add the above code and check?

Comment: Added. Still the same. In my wp-config now I have WP_HOME, WP_SITEURL, AND DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE. All of the 3 are pointing to the correct, full, HTTPS URL.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this in phpmyadmin in "prefix"_options table siteurl & homeurl in column option_name