# Add wordpress multi sites with different port number from 80

Tags: multisite, urls

Firstly I tried to install multi site into sub-directory.

At that time, I had problem with port because its not 80. But thanks to this article [Cannot install a network of sites - Wordpress and XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349039/cannot-install-a-network-of-sites-wordpress-and-xampp)
, I solved it.

So now, I tried to add Wordpress multi site in **My Sites** section of admin screen, but port number is not reflected in URL as below (2nd URL also should be `loclahost:800`)

[image]

Even if I edit andreplace this URL with `localhost:800`, it was saved as `localhost` automatically. (I think I need to modify some specifi PHP file)

Please someone tell me how to add `:800` in 2nd URL too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change the values in the wp-options tables. Or (maybe easier), go into the Multisite Admin area, then edit the sites. That gets you into a browser-based editing screens for all of the values in the wp-options table.

You can add the port number there.

You could also change the port number via the main htaccess file for your site.

Comment: I changed `siteurl and home` in wp-options but still nothing changed in Multisite Admin area

Comment: And browser-based editing from Multi Admin area  is also not working as I mentioned

Comment: Finally I coud change it via tables `wp_options( “siteurl” and “home”) ` and 
 `wp_blogs` .   [How do I change the Multisite URL?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/327424/how-do-i-change-the-multisite-url)